# OpenVPN Change ROUTE_GATEWAY after the IP of the gateway interface changed

Tags: linux, network-interface, openvpn, gateway

The server had `192.168.56.9` in before and changed to `192.168.56.10`, but the `ROUTE_GATEWAY` is still on the old IP:

```
$ openvpn --show-gateway
Sat Apr 18 13:18:54 2020 ROUTE_GATEWAY 192.168.56.9/255.255.255.248 IFACE=eno1 HWADDR=0c:c4:7a:72:3b:80
```

```
$ ifconfig | grep 192
        inet 192.168.56.10  netmask 255.255.255.248  broadcast 192.168.56.15
```

So I do not find some specific IP entry in the config files:

```
/etc/openvpn/server$ sudo grep -r 192.168.56 *
(nothing found)
```

So how can I change this gateway persistance?

Comment: Chances are that if you change your gateway you're going to need to re-establish the OpenVPN tunnel

Comment: Well... I did that like 10 times. The tunnel is established and I can reach other IP addresses in the VPN using `10.8.0.1`, but the traffic routed to the internet is not getting back to the client. I can actually see the Internet traffic coming in using `tcpdump`, but the server is not sending back the packages to the client. The tunnel worked perfectly for a half year, but changing the IP and default gateway now broke the internet connection. I can not find something in any config file.. So it may also could be an OS routing issue... The machine itself can reach internet.

Comment: This is really good detail. Can you please add it to your question where everyone can see it easily

Answer (score 0):

I tried tons of stuff from a lot of different sources, like checking the forward flag, setting different DNS settings, push different routes, setting different MTU. Nothing helped. Finally I did a re-install based on [this installer](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KashifHK123/OpenVPN-Auto-Installer/master/openvpn.sh). It took me like 15 minutes to re-enable the first client connection. The important things:

1. Stop the openvpn service (make sure it is not there any more, by checking `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 1194`
2. `sudo apt-get purge` (THIS WILL COMPLETY DELETE ALL CONFIGS AS WELL)
3. Do a fresh installation.